# disable past time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I want to disable the past time from dropdown once user selects date.
Below is the sample code:

```
function (declare, DateTextBox, locale, dom, lang, registry, ready) {
    var pad, update_current_available_times, get_hour_string;
    pad = function (n) {
        n = n + '';
        return n.length >= 2 ? n : new Array(2 - n.length + 1).join('0') + n;
    },
    get_hour_string = function (t) {
        var hour = pad(t.getHours()-1);
        var minute = pad(t.getMinutes());
        return 'T' + hour + ':' + minute + ':00';
    },
```

For minutes , i changed as below but giving wrong result.But when trying to disable past time from minutes giving unexpected results.

```
get_hour_string = function (t) {
    var hour = pad(t.getHours()-1); //added -1 to disable past time when used dojo1.9
    var d1 = new Date (),
   d2 = new Date ( d1 );
   d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes() + 20 );
   var minute1 = pad(d2.getMinutes());
    alert("d2.getMinutes() : " + d2.getMinutes() );
  return 'T' + hour + ':' + minute1 + ':00';
  }
```

Please suggest what are the changes in javascript file need to do to fix disabling past time from minutes dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you have it almost working..?

If I'm looking at this right, in your hour selector's onChange function, you just need to change:

```
useMin = 'T02:' + pad(now.getMinutes()) + ':00';
```

to

```
useMin = 'T' + pad(v.getHours()) + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) + ':00';
```

Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/27/

Edit: Ah, I see you are using a little trick to only show minutes in the minute dropdown. You could probably just use a dijit/form/Select instead, but it's a nice trick!

Since you have set visibleIncrement and clickableIncrement to 02:05:00 and 02:00:00, what the dropdown is actually showing is:

<kbd>00:**00**:00</kbd>
<kbd>02:**05**:00</kbd>
<kbd>04:**10**:00</kbd>
     <kbd>...</kbd>      
<kbd>22:**55**:00</kbd>

So when setting the minimum constraint on the minute dropdown, you actually have to set the "invisible" hour as well.

As an example, if "now" is 14:**34**:00, you have to take the 34 minutes, check which 2-hour "group" it belongs to: `34 % 5 = 6ish`.

Then get the hour from that: `2 * 6 = 12`

.. so the `useMin` for the minute dropdown in that case would be T12:34:00.

```
useMin = 'T' + 
    pad(2 * Math.floor(now.getMinutes() / 5)) + ':' +
    pad(now.getMinutes()) + ':00';
```

At least I think that would do it :) There may be a simpler solution.

Comment: Yes Frode as you mentioned it is working, only thing not working is 00 in minutes is always disabled. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/29/ . Thanks @Frode.

Comment: @user4103233 That happens because you always set useMin for the minutes to T02:00:00 unless it's the current hour. Here's an example of how I think you can do it: http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/32/ (I cleaned things up a bit, because I was bored.. :P)